# S2RegionCoverer not respecting min/max cell level?

Tags: android, google-maps, s2

When using Google's S2 geometry library to draw S2 cells on a google map widget, I'm getting cells that are outside my specified (constant) range.

```
S2RegionCoverer cov = new S2RegionCoverer();
cov.setMaxLevel(14);
cov.setMinLevel(14);
S2CellUnion cells = cov.getCovering(region_rect);
```

The resulting cells have levels 11-14, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is by design, and using this function instead, passing any point in the area as well as an empty ArrayList does the trick.

```
cov.getSimpleCovering(region_rect, bl.toPoint(),14,cells);
```